# How to find in python the amplitude and symmetry aspect by a ratio?

Tags: python, math, scipy, fibonacci, symmetry

I'm trying to find symmetry and amplitude ratios at least of 61% each of them for the Fibonacci ratios for a specific pivot point.

Let's said that `y[6]` it is the middle of the data and the highest point of the series. I don't know how to calculate if the values are symmetrical or not in high (y) and length (x). Any help would be appreciated.

Basically What it is the percentage of symmetry compared to the right side split-ted by the highest point of the series against the left side

[Picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV0uq.png)

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy import interpolate
    import numpy as np

    y= [10.5,10,12,13,10,11,16,10,9,13,10]
    x= np.linspace(1, len(y), len(y), endpoint=True)


    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
    ax.plot(x, y, color='red', label= 'Find Symmetry')
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do, please rephrase / add details.

Comment: Thanks for checking. What I am looking it is how program and find if the points  [10.5,10,12,13,10,11]  middle pivot [16]  comparad with   [14,11,13,18] are symmetrical in height and length for at least 61%

Comment: Why is 16 the "middle of the data?  If the data is  [10.5, 10, 12, 13, 10, 11, 16, 14, 11, 13, 18], wouldn't the 11 at index 5 be the "middle"?

Comment: We need a clearer definition of "symmetry and amplitude ratios".  Can you work out by hand and show in the question exactly what you are trying to compute, using the given sequence shown in the plot?

Comment: I have modified the the series to show you the 16 it is the highest point and I want to see if the data after that it is doing a mirror of the left side and for how much in percentage. 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

y= [10.5,10,12,13,10,11,16,10,9,13,10]
x= np.linspace(1, len(y), len(y), endpoint=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(x, y, color='red', label= 'Find Symmetry')

Comment: How do you measure the "similarity" of the two sides of the peak?  Mean square error?  Maximum absolute difference?  Maximum relative difference? Something else?  Also, how far from the peak should data be included?  All the way to the nearest edge?

Comment: I will think that maybe the Maximum relative difference would be a good way.  Yes the edges are the limits